# Two cannons are fired from a boat, boat A is closer and boat B further. Which gets hit first?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, distance

> A battleship (X) simultaneously fires two cannons towards two enemy ships.  One close by (A) and one far away (B).  The canon leave the battleship at different angles and travel along trajectories.  Which boat gets hit first?
>
> **Answer:** Boat B because the cannon doesn't need to go as high as it needs for boat B as it will take longer to travel way up than back down.

The distance on water between X and A is less compared to X and B. The cannons make this rainbow-like curved line as it travels to both boats (the line objects make when you throw them upwards). The top of the curve (when tangent is horizontal) for A is higher than B.  So wouldn't the cannon still take more time to travel from X to B than X to A?  Because if its tangent is lower in the air than A, its distance between X and B is still more than X and A.

How is the answer BOAT B?

Comment: A point worth learning is that the *rainbow like curved line* is properly called a *parabola*.

Comment: @OscarBravo keeping in mind that rainbows are not parabolic.

Comment: @KyleOman But they are both conic sections :-)

Comment: Is there a diagram that should be included with this question? Because the only way I can think of this working is if the gunners aim as described in @DavidRose's answer. And if that's the case, the gunners are the next thing to be leaving the ship at high speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cannon that shoots a ball at a constant velocity, there are two solutions that allow you to hit a target at a given distance.  (Mathematically, the solution is a quadratic with two roots.)

As an extreme example, if your target is 100 feet away, you can hit it by shooting directly at it, (with an almost insignificant ballistic arc), or you can hit it by shooting almost straight up, sending the ball thousands of feet into the air and having it fall back down 100 feet away.  So in your example, if you take the 'direct fire' path to the far target, and the 'parabolic' path to the near target, you can indeed hit the far target first.

Answer (score 0):

The duration of the trajectory is limited by motion in the vertical direction. That is, the path reaches its end when the canon ball falls to sea level (neglecting the target's height).

If a cannon ball is fired upwards more it will take longer to fall back down. This is true however far it travels horizontally.

To reach a nearer target a canon must fire upwards more (assuming it cannot adjust its muzzle velocity).

Comment: I had actually the same in mind at first, but consider this: Let's say the cannon fires exactly at sea level horizontally. The canonball immediately hits the water and the reached distance is 0. By adjusting the agle upwards, it will enter a real trajectorie and reach further distances up to some maximum and then smaller distances again until it fires straight up with 0 distance again. So if you can use a greater angle to hit a closer target, theres also a smaller angle to hit the same target - which should be faster.

Comment: Only if you can point the canon down, or low enough to hit the target side on. I think the intention of the question is that these are not options. Although it could have been clarified.

Comment: If you have a "minimum allowed angle" or obstacles i totally agree with you...

Comment: As a side comment: the “plunging” trajectories are usually preferred as the armour is less on the decks than on the sides.  The plunging trajectories are realistically rarely ballistic because of various factors (drag etc).  To avoid plunging fire from Bismarck, Adm. Holland tried to reduce as much as he could the distance from Bismarck to HMS Hood, but Hood was apparently still hit by plunging fire.  Unfortunately, no such tactical suggestion is made in the question.

Comment: This is almost certainly the meaning intended by the author of the question. The downward firing case (a) violates the unstated assumptions of the question, (b) is one of the annoying exceptions that make it difficult to write really unambiguous questions and (c)  breaks the pedagogical value of questions. Many students who missed the importance of the independence of the horizontal and vertical behavior in (idealized) projectile motion get their lightbulb moments from a discussion of this question (however it is phrased).

Answer (score 0):

It is true if the canon balls gets fired at the same speed and that all the boats are on the same height (which I assumed was the case).

**Proof:**

Assume both canonballs gets fired at speed $v_0$ at $y=height=0$. Then, by simple kinematics in a constant gravitational field, the canonballs' height are given by the following formula:

$$y(t)=v_0\sin(\theta)t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2 = \left(v_0\sin(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}gt\right)t$$

where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $\theta$ is the elevation angle of the canonball trajectory at the start. By simple logic, we must have that $0<\theta_B<\theta_A<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus, $\sin(\theta_B)<\sin(\theta_A)$. The canonballs will hit the targets after a time:

$$t_f = \frac{2v_0}{g}\sin(\theta)$$

And we have $$\frac{t_{fB}}{t_{fA}} = \frac{\sin(\theta_B)}{\sin(\theta_A)}<1$$ since  $\sin(\theta_B)<\sin(\theta_A)$.

Thus: $t_B < t_A$ and the B ship is hit first.

Comment: Seems to me the angle should be shallower for the nearest boat, i.e. $\theta_A<\theta_B$.

Comment: There is always two angles for one range; true. How would you prove then which angle is greater assuming $x_A$ < $x_B$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really a question about naval warfare; it's a simple projectile motion homework question. To make any sense of it, we have to assume that *both shots leave the gun at the same speed*. Also, we're considering the case where the nearer target is hit by a high, plunging shot (rather than a low-angle lob).

Then, the horizontal movement is irrelevant. We are only interested in the time of flight and for that, the only thing keeping the cannonball in the air is its vertical motion. For a body under acceleration, $v=at$, so $t=v/a$.

So we only need to know the vertical velocity in each case.

- For the long shot, the elevation angle is small, the ball has a small vertical velocity and so spends a short time in the air.
- For the close (plunging) shot, the angle and the vertical velocity, is large so the ball spends a longer time in the air.

So the distant target is hit first.

Mathematically,

$$
t = v/a
$$
$$
t = {v_0\sin\theta\over{g}}
$$
$$
\therefore t \propto \sin\theta
$$